How can I insert new arguments to this block of function calls that follow a pattern?
I have a number of lines as seen below:
arrowBuilder("right_front_wheel", inputMessage.front_right_lateral, Colour.Green, 4, "y"),
arrowBuilder("right_front_wheel", inputMessage.front_right_vertical, Colour.Blue, 5, "z"),
arrowBuilder("left_rear_wheel", inputMessage.rear_left_longitudinal, Colour.Red, 6, "x"),
arrowBuilder("left_rear_wheel", inputMessage.rear_left_lateral, Colour.Green, 7, "y"),
arrowBuilder("left_read_wheel", inputMessage.rear_left_vertical, Colour.Blue, 8, "z"),
arrowBuilder("right_rear_wheel", inputMessage.rear_right_longitudinal, Colour.Red, 9, "x"),
arrowBuilder("right_rear_wheel", inputMessage.rear_right_lateral, Colour.Green, 10, "y"),
arrowBuilder("right_read_wheel", inputMessage.rear_right_vertical, Colour.Blue, 11, "z"),

For each colour representation (e.g., Green, Blue), I want to add another argument in between the Colour object and int value and using the colour as a child of the object. This is an example of the result:
arrowBuilder("right_front_wheel", inputMessage.front_right_lateral, Colour.Green, NewObject.Green, 4, "y")

What techniques can turn the former into the latter?

lmao mispellings my bad

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Done! Thanks for the help!

Thanks die the feedback :-) Welcome to Vim!

Soliciting opinions is off-topic here, so I've reworded the question to avoid that part. That frees up answers to suggest multiple possible ways to solve the problem.

I'd probably just align the arguments, that way it's easier to see the differences. Then you can just use a block-select (ctrl-v) and insert the new ones. A lot of people don't like aligning them like that for some reason though so YMMV during the code review.

There are two classic ways.
Use a Regular expression:
Running on a selection of line:
:'<,'>s/Colour\.\(\w\+\),/\0 NewObject.\1,/

Remarks:

Regular expression could have a steep learning curve.
The set hlsearch setting highlight the part of the document that match your regular expression. It helps to understand what may go wrong in your expression.
The trace.vim plugin emulate the result of the substitution before running it. It makes writing substitution command much more friendly.

Define a macro:
Define the following a macro (using the qa command):
0/Col^Myf f p4bcwNewObject^[

Where:

^M stands for Enter and
^[ stands for Esc

Explanation:

0 go to the first column (good habits of macro recording)
/ColEnter search for Colour
yf  yank Colour.Green, 
f  go to the first space
p paste Colour.Green, 
4b go to the start of Colour
cwNewObjectEsc replace Colour by NewObject

Select the lines and run:
:'<,'>norm @a

Although it may look complex the idea is simple:

qa to start recording the macro
0 to position at the start of the line
do all the modifications you want to the line
q to stop recording the macro
select the lines you want to adapt
:'<,'>norm @a to apply the changes to the other lines


Note the 13 minutes gap between the initial answer with :s and the edit giving the macro solution? Mirrors my experience :-)

I love regular expressions but I would feel not complete to at least propose macros ;-) (a tribute to @Rich)

I love the regex approach, but the macros one are so intuitve! Thanks for the explanation!

@Friedrich Booooooo!

It would be pretty quick to get the macro right interactively, though, whereas the search pattern is tougher to "just see" for me: what would you do if the arguments weren't right next to each other?

For this particular case (wow, what a small nitpick): I'd probably do 0fC rather than 0/Col<Enter>, partly because I like the guarantee of staying in the line and partly because it's shorter. Doesn't always generalize, though.

I might even do 0fCyWWPBct.NewObject<esc> (/Colour would be nice if & worked, but the Colour to edit comes after the one to keep :/)

@Rich I added a macro to my answer and hope to have redeemed myself somewhat in your opinion :-)

@Friedrich That's the spirit! +1

I don't know if I count as an advanced user but I'd pretty sure use the :substitute command with a simple regular expression as below:
:%s/Colour\.\zs\w*, /&NewObject.&/

That's the literal string Colour. and then we start the match using the \zs atom. Everything after that is captured and will be available as & in the replacement. We do match any number of word characters followed by a comma and space.
In this example, a match may be Green, .
See :help /\zs and :help s/\& for reference.
We replace that with the match itself (the color name, comma and whitespace), followed by NewObject. and the match again.
When I was relatively new to Vim, I would do everything with a macro but now I find it more cumbersome than just writing a regular expression.
For the record, I got the expression above right on my first attempt (I'm writing this not to brag but to show how easy it is).
My main issue with macros is how to recover when you make a mistake.
Get a macro wrong and usually the easiest way out is to start over.
With an Ex command like :substitute, you can just edit the last command line.
Edit: a recursive macro
Just to show y'all that I'm not a no-macro guy — and to solicit upvotes from the macro fanboys, of course — have my macro solution.
The way I see it, when you write a macro,
you might as well write a recursive macro.
Before recording a recursive macro, we need to make sure the register is empty (to prevent evil things from happening).
Let's take the a register.
A quick and easy way to do so is the trademark Romainl Rapid Register Reset qaq.
For the recursion to terminate, we need to make sure the macro does not work on the line after the block.
This might be because the file ends or a motion fails.
Particularly, we cannot use / because it will search across lines.
I chose to go for the commas separating the arguments.
The recording I ended up with was:
qa^3f,yaWPlcwNewObject<Esc>@aq

That's ^ to go to the start of line. 3f, jumps to the third comma (I guessed and got it right the second time, you could also count commas or sneak there with f,f,f,). Then we yank the whole WORD with yaW, that's Colour.Green and Put it before the cursor. Go one right and change the word to NewObject. Leave insert mode, proceed to the next line with j.
As the last step, we recursively call the macro in register a. It's empty, so nothing happens right now.
We stop the recording and fire the macro with @a.
This time a is no longer empty and the recursion will do its awesome work, changing every line in the paragraph.

Yeah, thats a valid concern, I would really like to wrap my head around regex but sometimes for me it feels as though Im reading an alien's annotation (but its still really cool!)

@KhalidOwlWalid start reading with :help pattern, apply simple stuff and look up things you don't understand (yet). For most everyday tasks, you need to know only a handful of atoms.
